# Mover un elemento después de otro en una tabla

Tags: jquery, css, html5, bootstrap, table

Necesito ayuda con esto, mi código funciona bien, pero estoy utilizando una función que encontré en internet (aCollapTable) que permite ocultar elementos de una tabla y al hacer clic sobre el icono los despliega, lo que quiero saber es si es posible mover el elemento que despliega el resto de la tabla y dejarlo fijo del lado derecho, es decir, después del texto de la primera columna, el problema es que para que el CollapTable me funcione debo ponerlo en el `<tr>` y no en el `<td>` de la primera columna, entonces no se me ocurre una forma de hacerlo.

```js
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({ 
    aCollapTable: function(options) {
      var defaults = {
        startCollapsed : false,
        addColumn: true,
        plusButton: '+',
        minusButton: '-'
      };
      var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
      var self = this;  
      var parents = [];

      var _collaptable = function($table, $element, $parentElement, $display)
      {
        $parentElement = (typeof($parentElement) == 'undefined') ? $element.parents('tr').data('id') : $parentElement;
        $display = (typeof($display) == 'undefined') ? ( ($element.hasClass('act-expanded')) ? 'none' : 'table-row' ) : $display;

        $('tr[data-parent='+$parentElement+']', $table).each(function(key, item){
          $(item).css('display', $display);
          if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-expanded')) {
            _collaptable($table, $element, $(item).data('id'), $display);   
          }
        });

        spacer = _getSpacer($element.parents('tr'));

        if ($display == 'none') {
          $element.html(spacer + options.plusButton).removeClass('act-expanded').addClass('act-collapsed');
          $element.parents('tr').addClass('act-tr-collapsed').removeClass('act-tr-expanded');
        }
        else {
          $element.html(spacer + options.minusButton).removeClass('act-collapsed').addClass('act-expanded');
          $element.parents('tr').addClass('act-tr-expanded').removeClass('act-tr-collapsed');
        }
      };

      var _levelsAndParents = function(obj)
      {
        $('tr', obj).each(function(k, item){
          if ($(item).data('id')) {
            $parentElement = { id : $(item).data('id'), parent : $(item).data('parent') };
            parents.push($parentElement);
          }
        });
        parents = [];

        $('tr', obj).each(function(k, item){
          if ($(item).data('id')) {
            level = _getLevel($(item));
            $(item).attr('data-level', level);
          }
        });
      };

      var _getLevel = function($item, $level)
      {
        $level = (typeof($level) == 'undefined') ? 0 : $level;
        if ( $item.data('parent') == '' ) {
          return $level;
        }
        else {
          $parentElement = $('tr[data-id='+$item.data('parent')+']');
          return _getLevel($parentElement, $level+1);
        }
      };

      var _getSpacer = function($item)
      {
        spacer = '';
        for (i = 0; i < $item.data('level') ; i++) {
          spacer += '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
        return spacer;
      };

      var _bindButtons = function($table)
      {
        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-expand', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            expands = [];
            $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-collapsed') && $(item).css('display') != 'none') {
                expands.push($(item));
              }
            });
            $.each(expands, function(k, $item){
              _collaptable($table, $('.act-more', $item));
            });
          }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-collapse', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            expands = [];
            $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-expanded')) {
                expands.push($(item));
              }
            });
            $.each(expands, function(k, $item){
              _collaptable($table, $('.act-more', $item));
            });
          }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-expand-all', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            collapseds = [];
          $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-collapsed')) {
                _collaptable($('.act-more', $(item)));
            }
          });
          }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-collapse-all', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            collapseds = [];
            $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-expanded')) {
                _collaptable($('.act-more', $(item)));
              }
            });
          }
        });

      }

      return this.each(function() {
        var o = options;  
        var obj = $(this);
        _levelsAndParents(obj);
        _bindButtons(obj);

        // adding minus
        if ( $('tr', obj).length > 0) {
          $('tr', obj).each(function(k, item){   
            spacer = _getSpacer($(item));

            $minus = $('<a />').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)')
              .addClass('act-more act-expanded')
              .html(spacer + o.minusButton)
              .bind('click', function(){
                _collaptable(obj, $(this));
              })
              ;

            if ($('tr[data-parent='+$(item).data('id')+']', obj).length > 0) {
              $button = (o.addColumn == true) ? $('<td />').html($minus) : $minus;  
              itemClass = (o.startCollapsed) ? 'act-tr-collapsed' : 'act-tr-expanded';
              $(item).addClass(itemClass);
            }
            else {
              $button = (o.addColumn == true) ? $('<td />').html(spacer+'&nbsp;&nbsp;') : spacer+'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }            

            if (o.addColumn == true) {  
              $(item).prepend($button);  
            }
            else {
              $(item).children(':first').prepend($button);
            }

            // level class
            $(item).addClass('act-tr-level-'+$(item).data('level'));
          });

          // start collapsed
          if (o.startCollapsed) {
            $('.act-more', obj).each(function(k, item){
              $(item).click();
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  })
})(jQuery);

$('.collaptable').aCollapTable({ 
        startCollapsed: true,
        addColumn: false, 
        plusButton: '<span class="i">+</span>', 
        minusButton: '<span class="i">-</span>' 
      });
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xl {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xl-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xl-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xl-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xl-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xl-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #858796;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered th,
.table-bordered td {
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered thead th,
.table-bordered thead td {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
  color: #858796;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.table-hover .table-primary:hover {
  background-color: #b7c7f2;
}

.table-hover .table-primary:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-primary:hover > th {
  background-color: #b7c7f2;
}

.table-hover .table-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #cfcfd6;
}

.table-hover .table-secondary:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-secondary:hover > th {
  background-color: #cfcfd6;
}

.table-hover .table-success:hover {
  background-color: #aaebd3;
}

.table-hover .table-success:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-success:hover > th {
  background-color: #aaebd3;
}

.table-hover .table-info:hover {
  background-color: #b3e4ec;
}

.table-hover .table-info:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-info:hover > th {
  background-color: #b3e4ec;
}

.table-hover .table-warning:hover {
  background-color: #fbe6b1;
}

.table-hover .table-warning:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-warning:hover > th {
  background-color: #fbe6b1;
}

.table-hover .table-danger:hover {
  background-color: #f5b7b1;
}

.table-hover .table-danger:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-danger:hover > th {
  background-color: #f5b7b1;
}

.table-hover .table-active:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.table-hover .table-active:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-active:hover > th {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .table-responsive-sm {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-sm > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .table-responsive-md {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-md > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .table-responsive-lg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-lg > .table-bordered { 
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .table-responsive-xl {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-xl > .table-bordered { 
    border: 0;
  }
}

.table-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.table-responsive > .table-bordered {
  border: 0;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered collaptable">
  <thead>
      <tr style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">
        <th scope="col" colspan="5" class="align-middle text-center">5 GALONES (U)</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="align-middle text-center">5 GALONES ($)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;" class="align-middle text-center">
<td><strong>SUPERVISOR</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PROYECCION</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALCANCE</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PROYECCION</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALCANCE</strong></td>
    <tbody>
<tr data-id="1" data-parent="" class="align-middle text-left" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">
<td class="align-middle text-left" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>NOMBRE SUPERVISOR</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100%</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100%</strong>
</td>
<tr data-id="2" data-parent="1">
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">UN NOMBRE LARGO</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100%</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100%</td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de investigar encontré esta solución, añadir la clase en el css `.pull-right {float: right !important;}` y funciono.

```js
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({ 
    aCollapTable: function(options) {
      var defaults = {
        startCollapsed : false,
        addColumn: true,
        plusButton: '+',
        minusButton: '-'
      };
      var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
      var self = this;  
      var parents = [];

      var _collaptable = function($table, $element, $parentElement, $display)
      {
        $parentElement = (typeof($parentElement) == 'undefined') ? $element.parents('tr').data('id') : $parentElement;
        $display = (typeof($display) == 'undefined') ? ( ($element.hasClass('act-expanded')) ? 'none' : 'table-row' ) : $display;

        $('tr[data-parent='+$parentElement+']', $table).each(function(key, item){
          $(item).css('display', $display);
          if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-expanded')) {
            _collaptable($table, $element, $(item).data('id'), $display);   
          }
        });

        spacer = _getSpacer($element.parents('tr'));

        if ($display == 'none') {
          $element.html(spacer + options.plusButton).removeClass('act-expanded').addClass('act-collapsed');
          $element.parents('tr').addClass('act-tr-collapsed').removeClass('act-tr-expanded');
        }
        else {
          $element.html(spacer + options.minusButton).removeClass('act-collapsed').addClass('act-expanded');
          $element.parents('tr').addClass('act-tr-expanded').removeClass('act-tr-collapsed');
        }
      };

      var _levelsAndParents = function(obj)
      {
        $('tr', obj).each(function(k, item){
          if ($(item).data('id')) {
            $parentElement = { id : $(item).data('id'), parent : $(item).data('parent') };
            parents.push($parentElement);
          }
        });
        parents = [];

        $('tr', obj).each(function(k, item){
          if ($(item).data('id')) {
            level = _getLevel($(item));
            $(item).attr('data-level', level);
          }
        });
      };

      var _getLevel = function($item, $level)
      {
        $level = (typeof($level) == 'undefined') ? 0 : $level;
        if ( $item.data('parent') == '' ) {
          return $level;
        }
        else {
          $parentElement = $('tr[data-id='+$item.data('parent')+']');
          return _getLevel($parentElement, $level+1);
        }
      };

      var _getSpacer = function($item)
      {
        spacer = '';
        for (i = 0; i < $item.data('level') ; i++) {
          spacer += '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
        return spacer;
      };

      var _bindButtons = function($table)
      {
        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-expand', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            expands = [];
            $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-collapsed') && $(item).css('display') != 'none') {
                expands.push($(item));
              }
            });
            $.each(expands, function(k, $item){
              _collaptable($table, $('.act-more', $item));
            });
          }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-collapse', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            expands = [];
            $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-expanded')) {
                expands.push($(item));
              }
            });
            $.each(expands, function(k, $item){
              _collaptable($table, $('.act-more', $item));
            });
          }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-expand-all', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            collapseds = [];
          $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-collapsed')) {
                _collaptable($('.act-more', $(item)));
            }
          });
          }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.act-button-collapse-all', function(){
          if ( $('tr', self).length > 0 ) {
            collapseds = [];
            $('tr', self).each(function(k, item){
              if ($(item).hasClass('act-tr-expanded')) {
                _collaptable($('.act-more', $(item)));
              }
            });
          }
        });

      }

      return this.each(function() {
        var o = options;  
        var obj = $(this);
        _levelsAndParents(obj);
        _bindButtons(obj);

        // adding minus
        if ( $('tr', obj).length > 0) {
          $('tr', obj).each(function(k, item){   
            spacer = _getSpacer($(item));

            $minus = $('<a />').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)')
              .addClass('act-more act-expanded')
              .html(spacer + o.minusButton)
              .bind('click', function(){
                _collaptable(obj, $(this));
              })
              ;

            if ($('tr[data-parent='+$(item).data('id')+']', obj).length > 0) {
              $button = (o.addColumn == true) ? $('<td />').html($minus) : $minus;  
              itemClass = (o.startCollapsed) ? 'act-tr-collapsed' : 'act-tr-expanded';
              $(item).addClass(itemClass);
            }
            else {
              $button = (o.addColumn == true) ? $('<td />').html(spacer+'&nbsp;&nbsp;') : spacer+'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }            

            if (o.addColumn == true) {  
              $(item).prepend($button);  
            }
            else {
              $(item).children(':first').prepend($button);
            }

            // level class
            $(item).addClass('act-tr-level-'+$(item).data('level'));
          });

          // start collapsed
          if (o.startCollapsed) {
            $('.act-more', obj).each(function(k, item){
              $(item).click();
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  })
})(jQuery);

$('.collaptable').aCollapTable({ 
        startCollapsed: true,
        addColumn: false, 
        plusButton: '<span class="i pull-right">+</span>', 
        minusButton: '<span class="i pull-right">-</span>' 
      });
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xl {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xl-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xl-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xl-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xl-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xl-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
  }
  .col-xl-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
  }
  .col-xl-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #858796;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered th,
.table-bordered td {
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered thead th,
.table-bordered thead td {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
  color: #858796;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.table-hover .table-primary:hover {
  background-color: #b7c7f2;
}

.table-hover .table-primary:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-primary:hover > th {
  background-color: #b7c7f2;
}

.table-hover .table-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #cfcfd6;
}

.table-hover .table-secondary:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-secondary:hover > th {
  background-color: #cfcfd6;
}

.table-hover .table-success:hover {
  background-color: #aaebd3;
}

.table-hover .table-success:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-success:hover > th {
  background-color: #aaebd3;
}

.table-hover .table-info:hover {
  background-color: #b3e4ec;
}

.table-hover .table-info:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-info:hover > th {
  background-color: #b3e4ec;
}

.table-hover .table-warning:hover {
  background-color: #fbe6b1;
}

.table-hover .table-warning:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-warning:hover > th {
  background-color: #fbe6b1;
}

.table-hover .table-danger:hover {
  background-color: #f5b7b1;
}

.table-hover .table-danger:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-danger:hover > th {
  background-color: #f5b7b1;
}

.table-hover .table-active:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.table-hover .table-active:hover > td,
.table-hover .table-active:hover > th {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .table-responsive-sm {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-sm > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .table-responsive-md {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-md > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .table-responsive-lg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-lg > .table-bordered { 
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .table-responsive-xl {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .table-responsive-xl > .table-bordered { 
    border: 0;
  }
}

.table-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.table-responsive > .table-bordered {
  border: 0;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: auto;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered collaptable">
  <thead>
      <tr style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">
        <th scope="col" colspan="5" class="align-middle text-center">5 GALONES (U)</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="align-middle text-center">5 GALONES ($)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;" class="align-middle text-center">
<td><strong>SUPERVISOR</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PROYECCION</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALCANCE</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PROYECCION</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALCANCE</strong></td>
    <tbody>
<tr data-id="1" data-parent="" class="align-middle text-left" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">
<td class="align-middle text-left" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>NOMBRE SUPERVISOR</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100%</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100</strong>
</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;"><strong>100%</strong>
</td>
<tr data-id="2" data-parent="1">
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">UN NOMBRE LARGO</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100%</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100</td>
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;">100%</td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```